# PHP-DI using annotation injection with factory

Tags: php, php-di

i have a factory for creating an object.

```
Abbruchprotokoll::class => factory(function(ContainerInterface $c){
    return new Abbruchprotokoll($c->get(Request::class)->getRouterParam('stts-id'), $c->get(MySQL::class));
})
```

the factory is creating that object with a string and a dependency injection (MySQL Class).
In my `Abbruchprotokoll::class` i have an inject annotation:

```
/**
 * @Inject
 * @var \Smarty
 */
protected $smarty;
```

the problem is, that this inject annotation is not resolved. i think this is because i am on `FactoryResolver` and there is no `injectMethodsAndProperties()` like in `ObjectCreator`.

can i use injection annotations with factories in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use annotations with factories, you need to use `autowire(Abbruchprotokoll::class)` instead. `autowire()` asks for the class to be autowired, which resolves the annotations.

Comment: but how can i set the first constructor parameter? the first parameter is the ID of an entity and is gets from `getRouterParam('stts-id')` from the Request class

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#autowired-objects You need to use `->constructorParameter()`